# Difference between c++ and python solution of constructing bst from preorder traversal

Tags: python, c++, binary-tree

Although this solution does it in O(n^2).What really fascinates me here is that the same solution in C++ gets accepted while the python version throws error.I am a novice in C++.Any help will be appreciated.The root passed in buildBST function always assumes it to be Null in python .

C++ code

```
TreeNode *buildBST(TreeNode* &root, int ele) {
    if(!root)
        return root = new TreeNode(ele);
    
    if(root->val > ele)
        root->left = buildBST(root->left, ele);
    else
        root->right = buildBST(root->right, ele);
    
    return root;
}
TreeNode* bstFromPreorder(vector<int>& pre) {
    TreeNode *root = NULL;
    
    for(auto x : pre)
        buildBST(root, x);
    
    return root;
}
```

Here is the python version:

```
def buildBST(self,root,ele): 
    if root is None:
        root = TreeNode(ele)
        return root

    if(root.data > ele):
        root.left = self.buildBST(root.left, ele)
    else:
        root.right = self.buildBST(root.right, ele)

    return root
def bstFromPreorder(self,pre):
    root = None
    
    for i in pre:
        
        self.buildBST(root, i)
        
    
    return root
```

Comment: C++ code is _compiled_ whereas Python is _interpreted_; languages using the former approach typically produce much faster runtime results than the latter. As an example, C++ is a common language used for strictly real-time (embedded) targets as well as HW-intense computer games, whereas python shows its strength in other areas, such as tooling, glue for build systems, scientific computing and so on.

Comment: @dfri what i meant by error is wrong answer.In python the same code is producing wrong answer.

Comment: Probably it's not the **same** code. Please provide a [mcve] containing input and different output.

Comment: @ThomasSablik i wrote this python code looking at the c++ code.can you please tell me where i went wrong

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] containing input and different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**root** is a pointer ref in C++

```
TreeNode *buildBST(TreeNode* &root, int ele) {
```

**root** is just a parameter in Python

```
def buildBST(self,root,ele):
```

When your code changes the value of **root** before return it has no effect in your Python code.

Probably it should be:

```
def buildBST(self, root, ele):
    if root is None:
        root = TreeNode(ele)
        return root

    if(root.data > ele):
        root.left = self.buildBST(root.left, ele)
    else:
        root.right = self.buildBST(root.right, ele)

    return root

def bstFromPreorder(self, pre):
    root = None
    for i in pre:
        root = self.buildBST(root, i)  # changed here
    return root
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked.So the takeaway from this is that in python we can't send a parameter as a reference,whereas in C++ it can be sent as a reference.Am i right?